# How to spoof users to unit test ACL logic

Tags: php, acl, unit-testing, phpunit

Starting to think about unit testing access control permission logic in API calls.

Is there an established pattern for this?

Within [CiviUnitTestCase](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/CiviTest/CiviUnitTestCase.php) and [ACLPermissionTest](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/api/v3/ACLPermissionTest.php) there are these snips:

- Setup: `$config->userPermissionClass->permissions = array();`
- `$this->createLoggedInUser();` (creates and masquerade as a user, returning the new users contactID)
- `$this->setPermissions($permissions)`
- `$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton(); $session->set('userID', $contactID);`
- `$this->setupACL();`
- tearDown: `$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton(); unset($config->userPermissionClass->permissions);`

(assuming `$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton()`)

I'm still staring at the bowl...

Comment: some tips from Eileen [here](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/pzdzhozsnbdjmdmgjnzdzsn8ow)